# What is the usefulness of immutable StatefulWidget, and State in Flutter, but can make only one mutable StatefulWidget without state

Tags: dart, flutter

Why is flutter made with two separate **immutable** `StatefulWidget` and **mutable** `State` associated with it?. But is it possible to make one **mutable** `StatefulWidget` class and manage states inside it? I think it's pretty annoying to implement these two classes in order to *create* `StatefulWidget`.

Explain to me the actual usage of these two classes.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Sure got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not possible. 
StatefulWidgets are separated into 2 classes because one part is entirely immutable. `Widget` subclass *cannot* store any mutable field.

We are not in React where "Components" are mutable and the instance stays the same for the whole life of the component.

In Flutter widgets are very short-lived. We create a new widget instance every time we want to modify something.

---

It is however easily doable to reverse the lifecycles between State and StatefulWidget. And hide that "split in two classes" under an abstract interface

```
class Foo extends SimpleStateWidget<int> {
  @override
  int initState(BuildContext context, SetState<int> setState) {
    return 42;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, SetState<int> setState, int state) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => setState(state + 1),
      child: Text(state.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

If that's your thing, the interface is the following:

```dart
typedef SetState<T> = void Function(T state);

abstract class SimpleStateWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  T initState(BuildContext context, SetState<T> setState);

  void didChangeDependencies(
          BuildContext context, SetState<T> setState, T state) {}

  void dispose(BuildContext context, T state) {}

  void didUpdateWidget(BuildContext context, SetState<T> setState, T state) {}

  void deactivate(BuildContext context, SetState<T> setState, T state) {}

  void reassemble(BuildContext context, SetState<T> setState, T state) {}

  Widget build(BuildContext context, SetState<T> setState, T state);

  @override
  _SimpleStateWidgetState<T> createState() => _SimpleStateWidgetState<T>();
}

class _SimpleStateWidgetState<T> extends State<SimpleStateWidget<T>> {
  T state;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    state = widget.initState(context, _setState);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    widget.didChangeDependencies(context, _setState, state);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.dispose(context, state);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    widget.deactivate(context, _setState, state);
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    widget.reassemble(context, _setState, state);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.build(context, _setState, state);
  }

  void _setState(T value) {
    setState(() {
      state = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating objects with const and final keywords make them immutable, right? Are there any compiler optimizations. Any guidelines to follow to optimize flutter apps?

Comment: There's no compiler option. Use `const` instead of `new` whenever possible